# How can I insert elements in an empty (3,5) tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, b-tree

I know that people really don't like seeing homework questions here, but I just don't know what to do now.

For our algorithms lecture, I was asked to create a (3, 5) - tree. At the start it is empty and then we call various inserts on it.

However, I don't understand how inserting in a (3, 5) tree works. As many sources show (e.g. [this](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/ayg/CS251/slides/chap13a.pdf)) doing the same thing with a (2, 4) tree is fairly easy. 1 element will create an upper level of the tree and split the existing node in two parts. We also noted that in class. However this doesn't work for (3, 5) trees, does it? If I split my node in half there will be just 2 children for my newly created node. But there should be 3 since each node has to have at least "a" (in this case 3) children.

Realising that I'd need to create 3 new nodes from one. But what's the rule for it? Where do I split? And also wouldn't I lose the invariant we did note, that floor((b+1)/2) elements have to go to the left side.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi I am just adding it to the root. Maybe it didn't come out what my question truly was. My question is not about inserting one element. It's about various elements. In my case insert gets called 23 times with different elements. In the 2-4 tree I'd need to create a new root at the 4th call here, at 3-5 tree at the 5th if I got it right. But I really don't know how to operate this 5th insert.

Comment: `As many sources show` what do the notes of _your_ lecture show? How many children may the root node have? How many nodes does a node get split into? How many keys are there to re-distribute when a node needs to split? (The most specific tag is misleading, try [tag:b-tree].)

Comment: @greybeard my notes are more or less the same as the one I linked. That's what I am confused about. I am told to split if the elements in a node exceed b-1 and also to split that the "left part" as its says still has floor((b+1)/2) elements. But there is nothing else commented on which element should move up and how to split. Of course the comment floor((b+1)/2) should go to left is enough to define the upmoving and leftover elements for a 2-4 tree but not a 3-5 tree as I see it. So I hoped that there is some common way to do it.

Comment: `[my notes don't] comment on which element should move up and how to split` to resolve this may well be the purpose of this assignment. You already noticed that there are not (in contrast to lower bound <= half upper bound of children) enough keys to populate a second node _and_ "move up" one key. But: either the node is the root (where special rules may apply), or there is at least one key in the parent node adjacent to (careful here) _the subtree_ rooted at the node to split.

Comment: @greybeard Ohh okay. I will try.